# How do I set volume with the Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, api, slider, spotify, volume

I want to make a slider so I can control the volume of a Spotify track.
I read something about volume on this site, but I don't know how to connect it with the slider I made.
https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-volume/

This is what my slider looks like in code:

```js
document.getElementById('myRange').value //addEventListener('click', function() {

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/volume',
  type: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
  },
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify({

    "volume_percent": apiData.progress_ms
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

This is what it looks like in the browser:
[slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWJUU.jpg)

Can somebody help me with the JavaScript? I tried using this code, but I have no idea what I'm doing and it doesn't work.

Comment: May I ask, when does this code get called? It seems from the code you've provided that it may be in a click function?

Comment: It might be a good idea to hook your code to the OnChange listener of your slider.

Answer (score 0):

If you click `fill sample data` button on page you linked, it produces:

> curl -X "PUT" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/volume?volume_percent=50&device_id=0d1841b0976bae2a3a310dd74c0f3df354899bc8" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "

So it seems that you should use query parameters instead of passing them in request body. (`$.ajax` uses `data` as query parameters for GET requests, in PUT they're sent in request body)

```
var params = {
  "volume_percent": volume,
  "device_id": deviceid //optional
};
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/volume?' + $.param(params),
  type: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
  }
});
```

Also I advise to call it in button click listener or at slider's mouseup event, to avoid many requests:

```js
$("#myRange").on("input", function() {
  console.log("slider", this.value)
})

$("#myRange").on("mouseup", function() {
  console.log("slider mouseup", this.value)
})

$("#myButton").click(function() {
  console.log("button", $("#myRange").val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <button id="myButton">Set volume</button>
</div>
```